# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError when attempting to preview a BIRT report

Tags: java, eclipse, birt

I've been tasked to update a few BIRT reports, and every time I try and preview my BIRT report in Eclipse I get the the following error:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError cannot cast to java.lang.Exception`

Java version: 1.8.0_25

Tomcat: version 7

Eclipse: Juno Service Release 2 Build id 20130225-0426

I've increased the memory, and still nothing.

I'm on Windows 7

Comment: Did you try modding the catalina.sh file?

Answer (score 0):

1. in tomcat/bin/catalina.sh
2. add following in the beginning

```html
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"
```

Add it in the following way:

```html
#
#   LOGGING_MANAGER (Optional) Override Tomcat's logging manager
#                   Example (all one line)
#                   LOGGING_MANAGER="-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager"
#
# $Id: catalina.sh 1146069 2011-07-13 14:47:32Z markt $
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"

# OS specific support.  $var _must_ be set to either true or false.
cygwin=false
darwin=false
os400=false
case "`uname`" in
CYGWIN*) cygwin=true;;
Darwin*) darwin=true;;
OS400*) os400=true;;
esac
```

Now, Restart TomCat. See if that does it

Comment: should have mentioned, I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Aaah. Still, try pasting the first line and see?

Comment: where? In catalina.sh?  I don't have that file.  I've already looked for it.

Comment: Try googling your entire exception and see if you can come up with something. That's the best you can get as for now. I hope you get an answer soon